# How remove a specific substring between parenthesis using Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex

I am learning REGEX and I have the following string:

```
minchiase (se), minchiase se
```

My goal is to remove all the `se` and `(se)` from the string except the ones that are inside of a word. The final result should be:

```
minchiase , minchiase
```

So far I tried this `\b(se)` but I am only able to identify the last `se` but not the one between the parenthesis.

Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to achieve this goal using the regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
\bse\b|\(se\)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AwtEyo/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Match word boundary
- `se`: Match `se`
- `\b`: Match word boundary
- `|`: OR
- `\(`: Match opening `(`
- `se`: Match `se`
- `\)`: Match closing `)`